# Spring data mongo db count nested objects with a specific condition

Tags: spring, mongodb

I have a document like that:

```
'subject' : {
'name' :"...."
'facebookPosts':[

 {
 date:"14/02/2017 20:20:03" , // it is a string
 text:"facebook post text here",
 other stuff here  

 }

]

}
```

and I want to count the facebookPosts within a specific objects that their date field contains e.g "23/07/2016".

Now, I do that by extracting all the documents and count in the client side (spring ) , But I think that's not efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to aggregate your results.

```
final Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                    Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("facebookPosts.date").regex(REGEX)),
                    Aggregation.unwind("facebookPosts"),
                    Aggregation.group().count().as("count"));
```

Regex might not be the best solution, just an example.

`unwind` will split array into separate elements you can then count.

Create a class that will hold the count, something like:

```
public class PostCount {
    private Long count;
    // getters, setters
}
```

And then execute it like this:

```
AggregationResults<PostCount> postCount = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Subject.class, PostCount.class);
long count = postCount.getMappedResults().get(0).getCount();
```

Comment: Yes I find this doing the job, but what if I want just to count the facebookPosts that satisfies the condition, I mean i want just to count to count them without getting them and counting them myself.

Comment: mongoTemplate.count(query, clazz)

Comment: will it count the subjects or the facebookPosts within them ?

Comment: Updated the answer, I didn't read your question correctly, sorry

Comment: there still a small problem in this line PostCount postCount = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Subject.class, PostCount.class);          it tell me "cannot convert from AggregationResult<PostCount> to PostCount

Comment: I was doing it from the top of my head, didn't check what it actually returns, edited

Comment: also count in PostCount must be long not string, edited

Comment: I give it ....regex("14/08/2017") coz dates in db are in the format "14/08/2017 22:12:03" but I don't know why : when I give it an existing date it returns a big number (realtively) and when I give it an existing date it returns 0 P.s : for some dates, that big number is the same !!

Comment: Please ask a new question for this with concrete examples.

Comment: I asked another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45859710/spring-data-mongo-db-aggregation

Comment: I found the pattern, if the date exists (at least once) it counts all those posts (even the ones having diff date) , and if it doesn't exists it simply returns 0